# Is a string variable name stored in stack? Like an array name is stored in stack but its contents are in heap.

Tags: java, string

```
String abc = "dog";
```

Does a String variable name, i.e. abc, store a location in heap while itself being stored in stack like arrays? Or do string work differently?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Re the **name** `abc`:

If that code is in a method, the *name* `abc` isn't stored anywhere. It's just a stack variable referenced by index.

If that code is at class level, it defines an instance variable, and so its name is stored in the bytecode.

You can see the bytecode of a class by using `javap -c ClassName`, and of course, you can look at the contents of a `.class` file via your favorite binary file viewer (or if you like it old-school, `hexdump -C filename`).

#### Re the value of the string

The value of a string, like the value of all objects, is stored in the heap (conceptually, see * for more). String *literals* and other string compile-time constants, such as the `"dog"` in your code, are stored in [the constant pool](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.4) for the class (this is part of the `.class` format). When the class is loaded, those string constants are [*interned*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#intern--) into the string intern pool for the currently-running JVM. The string intern pool is on the heap.

#### Re the *reference* to the string

If that code is in a method, the *reference* to the string in the string pool is stored on the stack.

If that code is at class level, the reference is stored in the instance variable's storage, which is part of the object the instance variable is a member of. That object is conceptually on the heap.*

---

#### * "conceptually on the heap"

Oracle's JVM is quite smart. Within a method, objects created locally may well be allocated on the stack rather than the heap, as a performance optimization, since resetting the stack pointer when leaving the method is much simpler and faster than deallocating heap memory. However, if a reference to the object survives the termination of the method, the object is copied from the stack to the heap since, of course, the stack is about to be popped as part of the process of exiting from the method. And the JVM's decision about whether to do this is based on various factors, not least whether the method in question is in a "hot spot" in the code that's worth optimizing.

But that's a performance optimization in the JVM. Conceptually, objects are allocated on the heap.

Comment: @MTilsted: ***Doh!*** There I go, forgetting about reflection *yet again*. Thank you.

Comment: ahh, thanks for the updated answer, helps. I was having issues understanding how the stack and heap worked initially concerning strings. Got it now.

Comment: @billiesweasley: Glad that helped! Sorry I missed that you were curious about where the value and string object were stored at first.